# Image Resize returns a black background

Tags: php

PHP Image resize returns only black background.

I read all similar posts here, but none of them fixed my problem.

Here is the code:

```
$namef = $_FILES['image']['name'];

$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);

$location = "../userpictures/standard/".$mdid.".".$mzad;

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);

list($width, $height, $type, $att) = getimagesize($location);

$newwidth = 200;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,
 $width,$height);

$locations = "../userpictures/medium/".$mdid.".".$mzad;

imagejpeg($tmp,$locations,100);

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
```

I've checked whether this code was valid on php tutorials and it was ok with the code.

Comment: Do you have a black background on gif files with transparency, but jpgs are fine?

Comment: I don't allow gif files. Only jpg. So jpg doesn't have transparency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your images with imagecreatetruecolor, which create a new image of W x H filled in black.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php:

> imagecreatetruecolor() returns an image identifier representing a black image of the specified size.

Comment: and what should i do ? just delete $tmp2 variable ?

Comment: And this is not an error, this is a expected behavior. It depends on what you need

Comment: Image resizes, but when I view resized image its only black background

Comment: And just one question, you save the resampled image in $location, and then you save the uploaded file to that location... What the??

Comment: /* Write an image to $locations */ imagejpeg($tmp,$locations,100);
/* Save another image to same location */ move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);

Comment: oh does imagejpeg () function save image to the $locations ?